# Is there a Combine-y way to stop multiple requests being triggered?

Tags: swift, combine

I currently have code like...

```
var isFetching = false

func fetch() {
  guard !isFetching else { return }
  fetching = true

  apiPublisher
    .receive(on: .main)
    .handleEvents(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
      self?.fetching = false
    })
    .assign(to: \.foo, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

But I'm not happy with the way I'm stopping multiple requests happening like this. It works but feels clunky.

I feel like there should be a more "Combine-y" way of doing this.

Is there a more elegant/Combine-y way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is the fact that you have the entire Publisher subscription chain in a function (`fetch()`) that can be called by virtually any other code at virtually any time from any thread. In order to do this in a "more Combine-y" you need to limit that. So the question is what calls this `fetch()` function? If you wrap all those call sites in a Publisher and then setup a `trigger.flatMap { apiPublisher }` and set up the `flatMap` to ignore events while it's waiting for the current network request to complete.

Something like this:

```
    trigger
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) {
            apiPublisher
        }
        .receive(on: .main)
        .assign(to: \.foo, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
```

The important thing to note here is that you only execute this code once (probably in the viewDidLoad if this is a view controller. Then when you want to make the request, you send an event through the `trigger` Publisher. The `flatMap` will ensure that only one apiPublisher subscription will happen at a time.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much! I need to rework the code a bit but this makes absolute sense. 

Comment: Upon further research, I see that `flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1))` does *not* ignore elements, but it will ensure that only one network call is made at a time.

Comment: You might want to check this out. It seems to be a formalized implementation of what you did wrapped in an operator so it's more generally useful: https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineExt/issues/47

Comment: I use `flatMapFirst` extensively in my RxSwift code...

Comment: Yeah, the trick was turning the calls into a publisher and filtering those rather than trying to filter the apiPublusher itself. Nice trick. Thanks 